# Error: importing one of the Python modules required to run yum

Tags: linux, python-2.7, amazon-ec2, yum

I am using EC2-instance running Linux machine. By mistake, I removed Python

```
sudo rm -r /usr/lib/python
sudo rm -r /usr/lib/python27
```

Then, I tried to recover the Python from copying back from the /usr/bin/python

```
  sudo cp-r /usr/bin/python /usr/lib/python
  sudo cp-r /usr/bin/python27 /usr/lib/python27
```

Now, I am struggling to fix this error. Whenever I run any yum command e.g.

```
yum --version

There was a problem importing one of the Python modules required to run yum. The error leading to this problem was: No module named yum.
```

When I try to get the Python version, it shows Python is already installed.

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-10-195 ~]$ python -V
Python 2.7.12
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-10-195 ~]$ /usr/bin/python -V
Python 2.7.12
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-10-195 ~]$
```

Comment: spin up another micro instance for an hour and look at the difference between /usr/bin/python and /usr/lib/python , very different things

Comment: Do you mean running another micro instance? But does it not have same state as my current instance? Is it not possible to recover python from /usr/lib ?

Comment: no I want you to look at one that is not broken to see what it looks like, you will learn useful and basic things about python and how the linux filesystem is laid out

Comment: What distro are you using - Centos? Maybe this will be useful: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/109424/how-to-reinstall-yum

Answer (score 0):

use rpm, C program, to figure out what rpms you need to reinstall, download them and reinstall them